# Remove duplicates from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

Here is sample of my dataframe:
[image]

and I want my output to look like this:
[image]

To achieve this , I created a dictionary from my dataframe and
I want to remove duplicates from each individual column in the dataframe.

Here is my dictionary:

```
{'retailer_product_identifier pattern': {0: '9999999', 61: '999999999', 1941: '9999', 10328: '999999', 30097: '99999', 31333: '999', 37516: '99'}, 'last_seen_date pattern': {0: '99999999', 61: '99999999', 1941: '99999999', 10328: '99999999', 30097: '99999999', 31333: '99999999', 37516: '99999999'}, 'retailer_product_identifier pattern Count': {0: 94781, 61: 1108, 1941: 293, 10328: 1536, 30097: 448, 31333: 10, 37516: 18}, 'last_seen_date pattern Count': {0: 98194, 61: 98194, 1941: 98194, 10328: 98194, 30097: 98194, 31333: 98194, 37516: 98194}}
```

If you notice , the values in '`last_seen_date` pattern' and '`last_seen_date` pattern count' , they are the same. I want just one key-value pair for these ignoring the duplicates values.

> How can I do it?

Comment: The dictionaries inside  of `last_seen_date pattern` and `last_seen_date pattern count` are not  "the same" as you state. Their keys are the same, but the values inside are different.

Comment: can I ignore the keys to remove duplicates?or converting a dataframe to dictionary and then removing duplicates is a bad idea?These keys are basically indexes in my dataframe

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish all together. Using your posted dictionary, please update the question to include the expected outcome and what you've tried to accomplish that.  At the moment we cannot know what problem you're struggling with.

Comment: I have added my original dataframe and how the output should look like in my question.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code/text. Read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8805293) for reasons why. As for your update; What format is your expected output? If your expected output is a dictionary, post the actual dictionary you want the code to produce for you. And once again, please post the code you've already tried to accomplish that, even if it doesn't work, because then we can guide you more easily against a solution.